# self-taught compiler courses / good introductory compiler books?

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, dfa

Does anyone know of online course / university lectures that comprise a typical compiler course?  I've had theory of computing but unfortunately my school didn't offer a course in compiler construction.

I know there are lectures out there; I was hoping for recommendations for particularly good offerings.

Also, are there books for newbies to the field?  Something besides the dragon book, at least.  Beginners level is fine, I know there are a lot of intermediate-advanced texts on the market.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate (many times over) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler and others

Comment: i've never seen a better explanation of compilation than in the Dragon book. You could do worse than persevere with it.

Comment: I disagree.  I think that Modern Compiler Implementation In {ML,Java,C} by Andrew Appel is better than the Dragon book.  The dragon book is fine as a reference, but I think if you are looking for purely self-directed learning, Modern Compiler Implementation is a more complete and coherent work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Resources on Parsers, Interpreters, and Compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785/learning-resources-on-parsers-interpreters-and-compilers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: in case this SO questions doesn't get closed, do check this [duplicate SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler) which answers the question in a much more exhaustive fashion.

A couple of ressources on MIT's OpenCourseWare site:

[**6.035 Computer Language Engineering**](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-035-computer-language-engineering-sma-5502-fall-2005/)
[**6.827 Multithreaded Parallelism: Languages and Compilers**](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-827Multithreaded-Parallelism--Languages-and-CompilersFall2002/CourseHome/index.htm)

The former probably along the lines of what you had in mind. It also includes some of the lectures' videos.
The latter... positively a graduate level course. Also focus is more on multi-threading than the traditional compiling chain.  (But then again to to chunk code threads efficiently one must have a decent grasp of the semantics expressed in the original program...)

Comment: Does someone have the answers from that duplicate SO posting? It's been deleted due to moderation reasons.

Answer (score 5):

You can check out this course: http://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen4553

> **Course Information**
>
> High-level programming languages like
>   Python make programming a breeze, but
>   how do they work? There's a big gap
>   between Python and machine
>   instructions for modern computers.
>   Learn how to translate Python programs
>   all the way to Intel x86 assembly
>   language.
>
> Most compiler courses teach one phase
>   of the compiler at a time, such as
>   parsing, semantic analysis, and
>   register allocation. The problem with
>   that approach is it is difficult to
>   understand how the whole compiler fits
>   together and why each phase is
>   designed the way it is. Instead, each
>   week we implement a successively
>   larger subset of the Python language.
>   The very first subset is a tiny
>   language of arithmetic statements, and
>   by the time we are done the language
>   includes objects, inheritance, and
>   first-class functions.
>
> Prerequisites: Fluency in at least one
>   programming language (Java, C, C++,
>   Python, etc.). Students will do a lot
>   of programming in Python, but prior
>   knowledge of Python is not required.
>   The course will start with a crash
>   course on Python and Python is one of
>   the easiest languages to learn. Prior
>   knowledge of an assembly language
>   helps, but is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll have to see if he has more course info online than the website indicates-- looks like a lot of lecture material is either not there or hidden from public view.

Comment: @prasopes, thanks. I added a link without the year, because it might break again in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf ;)

That is a very basic introduction, you know that modern compilers are somewhat really complicated.